# Конфликтуют обработчики двух fileInput, в чем проблема?

Tags: php, yii2, fileupload

Есть в одной форме два FileInput. Один загружает картинки, а другой текстовые файлы.
Все лишнее я вырезал, для лучшей читабельности.
В контроллере пишу:

```
    public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $model = new Book();
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if( $model->image ) {
                $model->uploadImg();
            }
            $model->bookfile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'bookfile');
            if( $model->bookfile ) {
                $model->uploadFile();
            }
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
        else {
            return $this->render('update', compact('model'));
        }
    }
```

В моделе пишу:

```
    public $image;
    public $bookfile;
    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['image'],'file','extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
            [['bookfile'],'file','extensions' => 'txt,doc,pdf'],
        ];
    }
    public function uploadImg() {
        if($this->validate()) {
            $path = 'upload/store/'.$this->image->baseName.'.'.$this->image->extension;
            $this->image->saveAs($path);
            $this->attachImage($path, true);
            @unlink($path);
            return true;
        }
        else { return false; }
    }
    public function uploadFile() {
        if($this->validate()) {
            $ext = end((explode(".", $this->bookfile->name)));
            $this->bookfile = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$ext}";
            $path = Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/upload/global/books/'.$this->bookfile;
            $this->bookfile->saveAs();
        }
        else {  return $this->redirect(['index']); }
    }
```

Картинку прикрепляю с помощью расширения от CostaRico, yii2-images.
Проблема в том, что когда все строки заполнил и добавляю картинку(без загрузки текстового файла), то картинка успешно загружается. Если все строки заполнил и добавляю загрузку текстового файл (без картинки), то файл успешно загружается. Если же я указываю загрузку обоих файлов, то вылетает ошибка:

```
finfo_file(D:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\phpD547.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Подскажите в чем проблема? Разрабатываю сайт на Yii2 basic

Comment: а зачем вы сгенерировали $path в uploadFile() если потом ее не используете?

Comment: @WebCoder - Спасибо за замечание, теперь в uploadFile() написал: $this->bookfile->saveAs($path); И все равно тоже самое

Comment: Если честно я не могу понять почему оно должно сохранить. Смотрите вы изначально в свойство $this->bookfile  присваиваете рандомное имя  ( тоесть на данный момент это string ) , после вы пытаетесь вызвать у свойства некий метод для сохранения. тоесть вы пытаетесь сохранить строку как файл. Возможно я не прав. посмотрите перед  $this->bookfile->saveAs();  что находится в bookfile

Comment: только заметил . попробуйте изменить имя переменной public $bookfile на другое. потому что вы затераете файл

Comment: или измените эту строку              $this->bookfile = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$ext}";
 . вы когда принимаете модель , в свойстве   $this->bookfile  у вас file','extensions' => 'txt,doc,pdf'

Answer (score 0):

```
        public $image;
        public $bookfile;
        public $bookfileName
        public function rules() {
            return [
                [['image'],'file','extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
                [['bookfile'],'file','extensions' => 'txt,doc,pdf'],
            ];
        }
        public function uploadImg() {
            if($this->validate()) {
                $path = 'upload/store/'.$this->image->baseName.'.'.$this->image->extension;
                $this->image->saveAs($path);
                $this->attachImage($path, true);
                @unlink($path);
                return true;
            }
            else { return false; }
        }
        public function uploadFile() {
            if($this->validate()) {
                $ext = end((explode(".", $this->bookfile->name)));
                $this->bookfileName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$ext}";
                $path = Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/upload/global/books/'.$this->bookfileName;
                $this->bookfile->saveAs($path);
            }
            else {  return $this->redirect(['index']); }
        }
```

попробуйте так